# Is there a DataGrid "rendering complete" event?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid

When I load my DataGrid, I change the cursor to the wait-icon, load data into my ItemsSource from a database, and then set the cursor back to default. This works great, except for the fact that there is a delay in between when the ItemsSource is populated and when the DataGrid actually renders the data, so the cursor changes back to default too early.

Is there an event that is fired when a DataGrid is completely done rendering so that my cursor can return to default at the correct time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986431/busyindicator-to-datagrid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[FrameworkElement.Loaded event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx)

Occurs when the element is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction.

**Edit**

Or, just after you change the DataSource execute the following. So, it will reset the Cursor when application is idle.

```
    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { System.Windows.Input.Mouse.OverrideCursor = null; }, 
        DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

Comment: This looks promising, however, it appears that this event is only fired on my initial page load and not if I want to change or reload the observable collection that is bound to my datagrid. Do you know how I can get it to fire when I update the collection? I've already tried resetting the ItemsSource and DataContext properties.

Comment: Yes - I put all of my code that repopulates the datagrid inside the WaitCursor, but the cursor still goes back to default too early.

Comment: I'm also trying methods such as datagrid.Items.Refresh() or datagrid.UpdateLayout(), but nothing seems to be firing that load event again.

Comment: May be try something like this Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { System.Windows.Input.Mouse.OverrideCursor = null; }, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);

Comment: Waiting until the application is idle seems to do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Although I've just noticed that sometimes the cursor is the wait-cursor for 100% of the time, while other times it changes back too fast. I'll let you know if I can figure out why it's doing that sometimes.

Comment: Ahh - I believe it was inconsistent because I had asynchronous calls being made before I changed the ItemsSource. I made them synchronous and now it works all the time.